# imageJ how to get pixel rgb value?

Tags: java, imagej

i have a simple plugin which saves the polygon coordinates:

```
Roi roi = imp.getRoi();
Polygon p = roi.getPolygon();
for (int i = 1; i <= p.npoints; i++) {
// létrehozzuk az onvif féle vector-t
org.onvif.ver10.schema.Vector myVector = new Vector();
myVector.setX((float) p.xpoints[i - 1]);
myVector.setY((float) p.ypoints[i - 1]);
op.getPoint().add(myVector);
// IJ.log("Vector X Elements " + i + " :" + MyVector.getX());

        }
```

but i want to get the coordinates rgb values like this:
[image]

can you help me with this?
Thank you!

Comment: And what about HU value for CT Image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing the image is  32-bit RGB:

```
ImagePlus im = IJ.getImage();
ImageProcessor imp = im.getProcessor();

int[] rgb = new int[3];
imp.getPixel(X,Y,rgb);

IJ.log(Arrays.toString(rgb));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] r;

        for (int i = 1; i <= p.npoints; i++) {

            r = imp.getPixel(p.xpoints[i - 1], p.ypoints[i - 1]);



            ij.IJ.log("Red: "+ r[0]);
            ij.IJ.log("Green: "+ r[1]);
            ij.IJ.log("Blue: "+ r[2]);
            ij.IJ.log("index: "+ r[3]);

        }
```